# Does Python's sqlite3 module support prepared statements?

Tags: python, sqlite, prepared-statement

Does Python's sqlite3 module support prepared statements?
I've been Googling around, however, I can't find any examples of how to implement prepared statements. If so, can you please provide a snippet of code showing its usage?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like sqlite3 uses **parameter substitution**:

> Usually your SQL operations will need to use values from Python
>   variables. You shouldn’t assemble your query using Python’s string
>   operations because doing so is insecure; it makes your program
>   vulnerable to an SQL injection attack (see https://xkcd.com/327/ for
>   humorous example of what can go wrong).
>
> Instead, use the DB-API’s parameter substitution. Put ? as a
>   placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple
>   of values as the second argument to the cursor’s execute() method.
>   (Other database modules may use a different placeholder, such as %s or
>   :1.) For example:

```
# Never do this -- insecure!
symbol = 'RHAT'
c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '%s'" % symbol)

# Do this instead
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
print c.fetchone()

# Larger example that inserts many records at a time
purchases = [('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
             ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
             ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
            ]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', purchases)
```

This will achieve what I'm looking for. Closing this question.

Comment: Prepared statements and parameters are entirely different things. What were you actually looking for?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was a little unsure as to the differences. I'm looking to prevent SQL injection.